# How to list folders/directories that contain particular pattern files in them in python?

Tags: python-2.7, file

For example, if file contains extension `.parq` I have to list all the directories present in the folder:

- `/a/b/c/`
- `/a/b/e/`
- `/a/b/f/`

Here I have to list the directories **`c`, `e`, `f`** which has particular pattern files.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [os.walk](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.html#os.walk) to traverse over all the files and directories. Then you can do simple pattern matching in the file names (like the example you gave in the question).

```
import os

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'): #Traverse the current directory
    for name in files:
        if '.parq' in name:  #Check for pattern in the file name
            print path
```

You can either append the path to a list to use it later if you want. If you want to access the full file name you can use [os.path.join](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.join)

```
os.path.join(path, name)
```

If you want to access patterns within a file, you can modify the code as below.

```
import os

for path, subdirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for name in files:
        with open(name) as f:
            #Process the file line by line  
            for line in f:       
                if 'parq' in line:
                    #If pattern is found in file print the path and file   
                    print 'Pattern found in directory %s' %path,
                    print 'in file %s' %name
                    break
```